# What can and cannot run on the new Chrome OS?

Tags: google-chrome-os

[Google just announced a new operating system called Chrome.](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/07/introducing-google-chrome-os.html)  I'm a bit confused about what can and cannot run on this operating system.  In particular, does anything that requires a client side install work?  Will ASP.NET web apps work?  Will Silverlight work?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ASP.NET web apps will still work.  ASP.NET is a server-side technology, just like PHP, Ruby-on-Rails, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As best I can tell, it's just going to be a thin-client browser with local webapp support.

Answer (score 1):

Too early to tell, but I will bet my money on it having reduced functionality on computers with no or spotty Internet connection.

Comment: Though is does support gears for offline support

Answer (score 0):

If it runs on Google Chrome browser it will run on Chrome OS.

Comment: If it does not run on the Chrome browser, will it be able to run on the Chrome OS?

Comment: Information (the small pr blog) given so far consist only "Linux, X and 'new window manager'". That leaves alot for a debate what can be done on it. I'd suspect thou that there will be some sort of android layer in there but then again, thats just a hunch.

Answer (score 0):

From the announcement, the new operating system will be built on Linux and I imagine it will come with Google's Chrome web browser also.  You'll be able to browse any websites that you'd normally be able to browse, so you can look at ASP.NET, PHP, Silverlight, Flash, etc...

Since it's built on Linux, if you wanted to -host- an ASP.NET site, you'd have to use a solution like Mono.  ASP.NET is hosted using IIS, which requires a Windows server.

As far as local software, you wouldn't be able to run Windows programs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This can't be right.  Silverlight requires a client side install.

Answer (score 0):

On the client-side, apparently they are doing away with X11 ... and so no doubt you will only be able to develop client-side apps with the Google SDK..

I am also not sure I want an ad-company supplying me with my operating system!

For once, I agree with the Slashdot crowd. This is stupid.

Comment: If it is free, you will be surprised how many people will use it.

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with a lean Linux distro supporting X11/Gtk and the rest. I have run a fairly heavy-weight distro on SBCs before.

Answer (score 0):

No one knows. Only developers on Chrome OS know what's going to be on it.
Google gave really vague explanation on how the OS is going to work.
Only hint we have is that it will have really close relationship with Google's cloud, storing as much information and data as they can on the cloud, so that they are accessible in any Chrome OS (possibly).

Answer (score 0):

From the [open-sourcing announcement](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/11/releasing-chromium-os-open-source.html):

> First, it's all about the web. All apps are web apps. The entire experience takes place within the browser and there are no conventional desktop applications. This means users do not have to deal with installing, managing and updating programs.

So I suppose that nothing except web apps will work. As for Flash or Silverlight or Java applets, I guess if it works in the Chrome browser, it will work in Chrome OS.